# Pseudo-register Z load into a single register?

Tags: assembly, avr

I have trouble understanding the follow codes

```
;assume code for start of cseg
;and stack setup
.equ MAXNUM = 4
    ldi ZL, 0
    ldi ZH, 0 
    ldi r20, MAXNUM
loop_generate:
    lpm r0, Z+
    eor r0, ZL
...
```

First, what does it exactly mean by `Z+`? I google it and found "load Z and then increase Z by 1"?

Second, if the above is true, and Z is a pseudo-register, which means Z represents two registers. How can we load Z into r0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpm r0, Z+` loads r0 with the byte in program memory pointed to by the Z pseudo register, then adds 1 to Z.

Comment: And `eor r0, ZL` works, because `ZL` is lower part of `Z` which is exactly 1 byte.

Comment: @DavidGrayson It's program memory/flash http://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_LPM.html. Loads from RAM are via regular `ld`, for example `ld r1, Z+`